# how do i do a dynamic route in aws _route_table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I am using terraform to create my aws route table and its routes.

I am referencing base on this:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route_table

```
resource "aws_route_table" "r" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main.id
  }

  route {
    ipv6_cidr_block        = "::/0"
    egress_only_gateway_id = aws_egress_only_internet_gateway.foo.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}
```

How do I make it such that I do not repeat the route portion. And I can do it via an array of map and it will know I need 2 routes to be created?

example:

```
route = [
{
    cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main.id
  },
{
    ipv6_cidr_block        = "::/0"
    egress_only_gateway_id = aws_egress_only_internet_gateway.foo.id
  }
]
```

I tried with something like this:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {

  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.main.id

  dynamic route {
    count = length(var.routes)
    for_each = var.routes
    content {
      cidr_block = lookup(route.value, "cidr_block", null)
      ipv6_cidr_block = lookup(route.value, "ipv6_cidr_block", null)

      egress_only_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "egress_only_gateway_id", null)
      gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "gateway_id", null)
      instance_id = lookup(route.value, "instance_id", null)
      nat_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "nat_gateway_id", null)
      local_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "local_gateway_id", null)
      network_interface_id = lookup(route.value, "network_interface_id", null)
      transit_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "transit_gateway_id", null)
      vpc_endpoint_id = lookup(route.value, "vpc_endpoint_id", null)
      vpc_peering_connection_id = lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id_by_data", "false") == "true" ? data.aws_vpc_peering_connection.main[count.index].id : lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id", null)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What you tried does not work? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin my plan result ended up with modifying and creating 2 route tables which should not be the case. as there is only 1 route table to modify

Comment: Can you remove `count = length(var.routes)` and try again?

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) use only `for_each`, not `count`. However, you are using both `count` and `for_each` in your block:

```
  dynamic route {
    count = length(var.routes)
    for_each = var.routes
```

The above is incorrect, and `count = length(var.routes)` should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. i managed to figure out my other problem as well.
`vpc_peering_connection_id = lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id_by_data", "false") == "true" ? data.aws_vpc_peering_connection.main[count.index].id : lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id", null)`

i am using an `count.index` here. need to change to `route.key` and it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

My final answer will be this

```
resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {

  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.main.id

  dynamic route {
    for_each = var.routes
    content {
      cidr_block = lookup(route.value, "cidr_block", null)
      ipv6_cidr_block = lookup(route.value, "ipv6_cidr_block", null)

      egress_only_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "egress_only_gateway_id", null)
      gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "gateway_id", null)
      instance_id = lookup(route.value, "instance_id", null)
      nat_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "nat_gateway_id", null)
      local_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "local_gateway_id", null)
      network_interface_id = lookup(route.value, "network_interface_id", null)
      transit_gateway_id = lookup(route.value, "transit_gateway_id", null)
      vpc_endpoint_id = lookup(route.value, "vpc_endpoint_id", null)
      vpc_peering_connection_id = lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id_by_data", "false") == "true" ? data.aws_vpc_peering_connection.main[route.key].id : lookup(route.value, "vpc_peering_connection_id", null)
    }
  }
}
```